# Substitute Cipher in Java

Tags: java, encryption, substitution

I'm trying to set up a Substitution Cipher.  For my key, I'm using a random 256 byte array which is a permutation of the 256 possible byte values.

This is set up the following way:

```
public Substitute()
{
    key = new byte[256];
    List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    for(int i = -128; i < 128; i++)
    {
        list.add((byte)i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    Byte[] tmp = new Byte[256];
    tmp = list.toArray(tmp);

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        key[i] = tmp[i];        
    }
}
```

I then encode/decode messages with the following methods:

```
public byte [] encode(String S)
{
    byte[] plain = S.getBytes();
    byte[] encoded = new byte[plain.length]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < plain.length; i++)
        encoded[i] = (byte)(key[plain[i]]);

    return encoded;
}

public String decode(byte [] bytes)
{
    byte[] plain = new byte[bytes.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        plain[i] = (byte)(Arrays.asList(key).indexOf(bytes[i]));

    return new String(plain);
}
```

Something is going wrong along the way, and anything I decode just comes back as a string of `ÿ`

I'm not sure where I went wrong or if this is the most efficient way of doing things.  I have to keep the same function signatures and general method, but the implementation details are up to me.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem - as I expect you've guessed - is here:

```
plain[i] = (byte)(Arrays.asList(key).indexOf(bytes[i]));
```

what you need to do is find the bye in the `key` and replace it with is offset.

Something like

```
plain[i] = key.indexof(byes[i]);
```

but that won't work of course - and you need to fold in the `-128` you added to the encode.

Trying to put together some test code - will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks!  I've modified my program, here's what I have now, and it appears to be working... However, I'm using it in conjunction with other programs and its causing a crash there...

Comment: That issue was small error I was making elsewhere.  As far as I can tell, the solution I posted is accurate

Answer (score 1):

The issue, ans OldCurmudegeon said, was with:

```
plain[i] = (byte)(Arrays.asList(key).indexOf(bytes[i]));
```

So I modified my program to include a `decryptKey` which was the reverse of the key, allowing me to find indices for each value.

The reverse was done was such:

```
public byte [] reverseKey(byte[] key)
{
    byte[] reverse = new byte[key.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        reverse[key[i] + 128] = (byte)i; //makes sure to account for negative values.
    }

    return reverse;
}
```

I then tweaked my decode method to use this new `decryptKey`:

```
public String decode(byte [] bytes)
{
    byte[] plain = new byte[bytes.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        plain[i] = (byte)decryptKey[bytes[i] + 128];

    return new String(plain);
}
```

This is functional as far as I can tell.